# Create a windows share on a set of computers when it's not connected to the domain?

Tags: windows-server-2008, windows-7, network-share

This is going to be an odd question but here it goes.

I have 13 buses. Each bus contains its own subnet. (255.255.255.0) While docked in their stations, they connect to the network. Each bus has a windows server 2008 enterprise edition which is the sql server for that bus along with other things. We are now required to have a share on the bus server that the thin clients are able to connect to. Each windows 7 thin pc client has a non-administrator domain login. Each member of the crew knows this login's password and is able to login while off the network.

I have created a share using the local administrator on the server while off the network and mapped it on the server as the Z drive. Under the Advanced sharing > Permissions Everyone has read permissions. Under the Caching, I have selected All files and programs that users open from the shared folder are automatically available offline. I have also added each thin client and it's IP address inside of the etc/hosts file of the server. Each thin client has each other thin client and the server's name and IP address inside of them as well.

While connected to the network, I am able to access the share from a thin client. While off the network, I receive no login service available error.

How do I setup this share? What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Is the error "no login service available" or "no logon server avilable"? Do the "other things" you mention about the bus server include it being a RODC? http://support.microsoft.com/kb/949048

Comment: The local user failed due to the bus not being connected to the network. The reason for the fail is when off the network there is no DC. Thus, I am going to remove all devices from the domain. Then setup the share. Then rejoin to the domain. Setup a local user for the auto users in the thin clients this way they will connect to the share on the bus that is shared to the local subnet. I will do this tomorrow. Thank you for your help. I will update tomorrow afternoon with the results.

Comment: You shouldn't need to remove anything from the domain.  Local accounts don't fail from not being connected to the network because they're local.  The Thin clients can still logon with domain accounts, no reason to change that.  Don't create local accounts on all the thin clients, its not necessary.  On the server on the bus, run "compmgmt.msc" and add a local user called `ShareAccessAcct` or whatever you want.  From the thin clients, connect to the server using `ServerHostname\ShareAccessAcct` and password.

Comment: @Spencer5051, Your suggestion worked. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

The solution to the problem is to create a local account using compmgmt.msc.

*compmgmt.msc > System Tools > Local Users and Groups > Users > Right Click and Add user
compmgmt.msc > System Tools > Shared Folders > Shares > Create your share*

Then after setting the permissions to allow the user you added to have read rights to the share. Got to your thin client or other PC on the area.

*Right click on the computers > Map A Drive > Check both "Reconnect at logon" And "Connect using different credentials" Then Click Browser > Select your host > Select your share. Enter hostname\created user account.*

Now the drive is mapped to the local server instead of the domain.

I removed the bus off the domain and restarted the computers. Each computer was able to keep it's settings. Now to validate and implement.

This suggestion was given by [Spencer5051](https://serverfault.com/users/220509/spencer5051)

Answer (score -1):

I am not quite certain about what you want to get resolved here, but I'll try to the best of my ability to understand and provide you an overview of what it is you are doing wrong and what you have to do to get this to work properly.

Firstly, you mention each bus docks back to the network after a period of X min/hours away and during that time, I assume they sync from the network. 
Secondly, you mention you created local "shares" that are spawned by a local administrator on the local computer. 
Thirdly, your thin clients can connect to the computer (locally, I assume) whilst it's off the network.

So. I have deduced that you have only local computers, not domain computers and no domain servers.

You have two options here:

1) You can create a domain controller/FQDN that will house DFS shares for each bus. You can then control the information centrally and enable offline files for DFS. This will permit the servers on each bus to retain the data and provided you enable the ability in the forest's group policy, you can push it to the clients.

2) You don't install a domain but leave the share as it is. You mention that while off the network, no logon service is available, that is because however you are connecting, the client cannot see the logon server anymore. A simple reboot and direct connection to the bus server will fix this. (My previous SF answer sheds more light on this: [nas - Synology and Active Directory](https://serverfault.com/questions/611980/synology-and-active-directory-no-logon-servers-available/628052#628052).

2.1) If you wish to connect your thin client directly to the server without passing through a switch/hub, then you will need a crossover [[Wikipedia] Ethernet Crossover](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ethernet_crossover_cable) or a NIC that allows for Auto-MDIX (senses whether the connection comes from a like device or non-like device): [Medium Dependent Interface (MDI)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Medium_Dependent_Interface)

Your problem can be fixed by following the "nas - Synology and Active Directory" post I submitted. Just make sure that you either have DHCP running on that server to give the thin client an address, or static address on the same subnet and address range.

I hope it helps. :) It's a common problem within Windows whereby the "location" of the server is gone. You just need to fine tune it to handle disconnects for X min/hours and then when the bus docks back, it syncs and connects/your thin clients need to be constantly connected to the server.

Remember your thin clients are logging into the server hence the logon server issue.

:)

EDIT: Forgot to mention that if you have a pre-existing domain and the AD DS is not on the remote roaming servers, you won't be able to login unless it's cached on the client. From there, use the FQDN\username and log in, just make sure that the share is located on the bus server and is accessible from the roaming network (see subnet requirements above)